# Add angular to window type definition

Tags: angular, typescript, cypress

I'm in the process of getting Cypress up and running.  I'd like to have Cypress directly call some of my functions to check their output.

I can't seem to get a reference to angular though within my test.  I saw some info about adding a custom "angular" property to the global window object but I still can't seem to figure it out.

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3068#issuecomment-454109519

Based on the example above, how would I create a custom property so that I can get ahold of the angular object within Cypress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an `index.d.ts` in `cypress/support` with the following (to add a property called `ng` for example):

```
interface Window {
  ng: {
    probe: typeof import("@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/debug/ng_probe").inspectNativeElement
    // // un-comment if you need these for some reason:
    // ɵcompilerFacade: import("@angular/compiler/src/jit_compiler_facade").CompilerFacadeImpl
    // coreTokens: {
    //   ApplicationRef: import("@angular/core").ApplicationRef
    //   NgZone: import("@angular/core").NgZone
    // }
  }
}
```

Then you should be able to use:

```js
cy.get('.some-ng-element').then(($el) => {
  const el = $el[0]  // get the DOM element from the jquery element
  const win = el.ownerDocument.defaultView // get the window from the DOM element
  const component = win.ng.probe(el).componentInstance
})
```

Comment: Hmm...doesn't work.  I even tried just logging out `win.ng` but it's undefined.

Comment: Whoops, forgot .defaultView after ownerDocument, tell me if that works

Comment: @JustinYoung for better type completions, see the updated code for extending the `Window` interface.